# Can't properly use variable from other script in Unity

Tags: variables, scripting

I have following problem, so i can't use variable form other script. In my game there is difficulty select screen, and when user choose it's level it should give proper value to variable. Script looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DifManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public float dif;

public void easy()
{
    dif = 1.05f;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("matchlenght");
}

public void normal()
{
    dif = 1.15f;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("matchlenght");
}

public void hard()
{
    dif = 1.4f;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("matchlenght");
}
}
```

In another script on the gameplay scene i want to use dif variable to set DifficultyMultiplier and it looks like it:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball2 : MonoBehaviour
{

private matchlength mlength;
public float difficultMultiplier;
public float minXspeed = 0.8f;
public float maxXspeed = 1.2f;

public float minYspeed = 0.8f;
public float maxYspeed = 1.2f;
public DifManager d;
private Rigidbody2D ballRigidbody;
private GameObject secondPaddle;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    d = gameObject.GetComponent<DifManager>();
    secondPaddle = GameObject.Find("Paddle2");
    difficultMultiplier = d.dif;
    mlength = gameObject.GetComponent<matchlength>();
    ballRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    ballRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(Random.Range(minXspeed, maxXspeed) * (Random.value > 0.5f ? 
     -1 : 1), Random.Range(minYspeed, maxYspeed) * (Random.value > 0.5f ? -1 : 1));
    
}
```

I'm still getting error about Null reference, so i suppose that is something wrong with getting proper value. What am i doing wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied these two classes and everything works fine, so the issue caused by another variable,
or,

are these two classes inside the same game object? this is the only way I have found to cause this exception...
if this is it,

use this line to get "DifManager"

```
d =  GameObject.Find("yourGameObject").GetComponent<DifManager>();
```

or

```
Public GameObject s // the game object have "DifManager" class

 d = s.GetComponent<DifManager>();
```

if not,

try debugging your code...

and see where the exception refers to?

like `Ball2.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Ball2.cs:23)`

Edit:

as shown in comments,
the issue is the 2 classes on different scenes, so `GameObject.Find` and `public GameObject` will give null

to solve this issue, Use `PlayerPrefs`

instead of `dif = 1.05f` add `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("dif", 1.05f);`
for all `dif` states

and instead of `difficultMultiplier = d.dif;` add `difficultMultiplier = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("dif");`

and remove "d"

Comment: Thanks for your help, i've tried this, but it nothing changes at all.

Comment: explain what happened please,
first, are these two classes inside the same game object?
if not, make sure you have set the game object name correctly

Comment: Thanks for your time and advices, mate. So i have 3 scenes: first one where you choose difficulty, there is gameobject, which is my controllerer , it's called DifficultyManager and this gameobject has attached script DifManager, which you can see above. Second scene is where you choose how many points you or opponent has to end game and check who wins.Third one is gameplay scene, there are 4 gameobjects - ball, two paddles and game controller. Script Ball2.cs is attached to ball gameobject and this script you can view above. gameobject names should be correct cause i have coppied it's names.

Comment: now I get it, 

my script result will set d to 'null' because it's trying to find an object in another scene,
try using PlayerPrefs, set your "dif" on DifManager, and get "dif on
Ball2

Comment: Can you write more clearly what do you mean "using PlayerPrefs". Sorry but i don't get it ;).

Comment: instead of "dif = 1.0f"..... add
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("dif", 1.05f); ....
for 3 dif states .....
instead of "difficultMultiplier = d.dif;" add...difficultMultiplier = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("dif");

Comment: and remove "d", it always null

Comment: perfect! now I'm going to edit my answer to the new solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code looks to be working fine.

Assuming the game is working fine and you are getting Null Reference when you hit the play.

You check in your code by checking whether the

> d = gameObject.GetComponent();

is being referenced or not.

```
void Start()
{
 d = gameObject.GetComponent<DifManager>();
 secondPaddle = GameObject.Find("Paddle2");

   if (d!= null)// Checks if the object exist, based on this you can try debugging.
   // you can add the same for SecondPaddle and mlength and check if its not equals to null....
  {

    difficultMultiplier = d.dif; 

  }

mlength = gameObject.GetComponent<matchlength>();
ballRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
ballRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(Random.Range(minXspeed, maxXspeed) * (Random.value > 0.5f ? 
 -1 : 1), Random.Range(minYspeed, maxYspeed) * (Random.value > 0.5f ? -1 : 1));

}
```

Also try adding **Debug.Log()** to check what value is being returned.

**Additional Query For passing different values for the Same Scene**

Assuming that you want to load the same Scene based upon the difficulty level and just want to get the different **dif** value.

Please find the below code changes that is required.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DifManager : MonoBehaviour
{

public static float dif=0.0f; // change value as static

public static float GetdiffVariable() { return dif; }//We will take this function to return us the "dif" value based upon the Scene in our case its easy,normal or hard

public void easy()
{
    dif = 1.05f;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("matchlenght");
}

public void normal()
{
    dif = 1.15f;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("matchlenght");
}

public void hard()
{
    dif = 1.4f;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("matchlenght");
}
}
```

Once we had the function to return our value from our scene next we make changes to Ball2 Script

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball2 : MonoBehaviour
{

private matchlength mlength;
public float difficultMultiplier;
public float minXspeed = 0.8f;
public float maxXspeed = 1.2f;

public float minYspeed = 0.8f;
public float maxYspeed = 1.2f;
public DifManager d;
private Rigidbody2D ballRigidbody;
private GameObject secondPaddle;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //d = gameObject.GetComponent<DifManager>(); we dont need this line anymore we can directly assign as we are only concerned with the return value for our Scene Difficulty

   
    difficultMultiplier = d.GetdiffVariable();//Should return you different values based on the easy, normal or hard.

    Debug.Log("difficultMultiplier");// cross verify in console
    secondPaddle = GameObject.Find("Paddle2");

    mlength = gameObject.GetComponent<matchlength>();
    ballRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    ballRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(Random.Range(minXspeed, maxXspeed) * (Random.value > 0.5f ? 
     -1 : 1), Random.Range(minYspeed, maxYspeed) * (Random.value > 0.5f ? -1 : 1));
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now i'm getting difficultMultiplier value 1.1f no matter which difficulty level i choose. I don't know how to fix it. Maybe you can help me one more time with it?

Comment: Hi there i have tried this one, and it nothing changes at all. But i know from where is 1.1 value that dif always has. It's assigned in unity editor to gameobject (controller with script DiffManager attached), but i don't know how to change it, to get different variables i want.

Comment: @Pjoter DiffManger is your Scene Manager right? it will be part of different scene I assume, Dont attach the Scene Manager in the game Scene, you need to make function call from Diff Manger to your current Scene having the gameobject.